# Win 10: Any way to determine which monitor's taskbar the user clicked to launch an application?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, multiple-monitors

I have a multi-monitor config that duplicates the task bar on each monitor. I also have an application with an icon in the taskbar (thus it shows on all monitors), and I'd like this application to behave differently depending on which monitor the click came from.

Is it possible to determine which monitor's taskbar was used to launch that app? I would just need the API function names (rather than actual code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not what I asked in my OP is possible, I found a way to do what I want: Immediately upon launch, I obtain the current mouse position in absolute coordinates. This allows me to determine which monitor the mouse is on, which is almost certainly the monitor holding the taskbar icon used to launch the application.